# Git to GitHub - Failed to connect to port 443: Connection refused

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh, https

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04.3 via Oracle's Virtual Box with the parent OS being windows 8.1. I've installed Git on the VM, and have setup a GitHub account.

Using the terminal, I have entered in my username, e-mail, and have set up the remote connection between my local file and my repository. All of that went without a hitch. I then created a README.txt file to try and practice commits and pushes. In the terminal, and in the correct directory, I type `$ git add README` then `$ git commit -m 'Practicing Git'`, the terminal then outputs:

```
[master (root-commit) f3dc37d] Practicing Git
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
create mode 100644
```

So everything seems to be going well, but then I try and push the commit to the repository `$ git push origin master`, and the terminal outputs this message:

`fatal: unable to access 'https://CaliKane/RemindMeApp.git/': Failed to connect to CaliKane port 443: Connection refused`

- I have reviewed prior questions, and their answers, on SO and Google, but most of them discuss the issue of proxies setup at their work locations.
- I have double checked that I entered in the remote url correctly
- I have turned off my Norton Antivirus smart firewall and antivirus protection

This is currently being tried on my home computer without any proxies. I know that I can try and setup the push through SSH, but am not very familiar with the process, and would rather stick with https if possible, as it seems to be the best option. I'm not sure what the issue could be except for maybe running git on a VM? If anyone has suggestions, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Is CaliKane really a host name? You mention "github". Then the url should have "github.com" in it.

Comment: Try `https://github.com/CaliKane/RemindMeApp.git`

Comment: @Thilo When I setup the remote I do put github.com in as the host name, for some reason when the error outputs it doesn't have that included. I just tried it again to double check. I type `$ git remote add origin https://github.com/CaliKane/RemindMeApp.git`, then the terminal outputs `fatal: remote origin already exists.` When i try and push again, I get the same error output as above in my original question. Thanks for pointing that out though, I hadn't noticed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GitHub then you are missing part of the remote URL it should be:

https://github.com/CaliKane/RemindMEApp.git

This assumes your username is CaliKane on github and your project name is RemindMEApp.git

I have checked the URL and this is your remote host.

Comment: When I am adding the remote, I am using the github.com host name, but for some reason the error message is not showing that, but I did double check that. Also there was a typo in my original question, my project name is RemindMeApp, and not RemindMEApp, I fixed that. However, I typed the correct project name in the terminal command and also check that it was the same on github.com. Any other suggestions? Thanks for the help!

Comment: In the terminal, navigate to your projects directory, then do sudo nano .git/conf and make sure that all of the urls are correct.

Comment: I did that, and it pops up a terminal looking window that is labeled "GNU nano 2.2.6  File: .git/conf". The window is all blank except for navigation commands on the bottom of the screen. I'm assuming this is not correct then?

Comment: Sorry it should be: sudo nano .git/config

Comment: Yeah, it is the wrong url, I'm not sure why it is not putting the correct host name in there, I know that I am entering it correctly. Maybe if I delete the old remote, and enter it in again, it may fix the problem? Whenever I enter the remote name in with the correct url, it tells me that it already exists. `[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://CaliKane/RemindMeApp.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

Comment: You should be able to edit that in nano and then hit ctrl x to exit and press y to save.